# Getting Cache connection error: "Cache Security Error"

Tags: database, intersystems-cache

I am trying to connect to a Cache database. I can connect to to the database in question with a predefined ODBC DSN connection with my username and password.

What I want to do is use a SQL connector, `Intersystems.Data.CacheClient.dll` to connect. I reference the DLL file, and pass my connection string containing the server IP, namespace and my login credentials, but the `connection.open()` gives me `Cache Security Error`.

I did grant permission in Cache to allow "ALL" permissions to my user.

Comment: It could be as simple as incorrect credentials. Could you show us details from the [Audit Log](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20131/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCAS_audit)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the audit log - in the SMP go to System Administration -> Security -> Auditing -> View audit database. I'm guessing that %Service_Bindings isn't enabled.

Comment: Nope it is not, how do I enable this.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this until now- go to System Administration -> Security -> Services and click on it and then click 'enabled'.